# composer.phar and ionCube 4.0.7

Tags: symfony, composer-php, ioncube

I was trying to get composer for init a symfony2 project.
But Wwhen I try this command

```
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I get this error:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

Your ionCube Loader extension (4.0) is incompatible with Phar files.
Upgrade to ionCube 4.0.9 or higher or remove this line (path may be different) from your `php.ini` to disable it:
    zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /etc/php.ini
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.
```

I've just take a look inside my php.ini, and find that my ionCube  Loader version is 4.0.7.
Is there a way to get composer.phar with this version of ionCube Loader avoiding a PHP update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, old ionCube versions just make phar files fail, so they are not compatible with composer.phar. You can however install a new version of the ioncube loader withtout updating PHP entirely I would imagine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. How can I do this ionCuhbe upgrade?